# how to exclude varnish cache for some pages by header?

Tags: varnish

I'm using varnish caching
and now i want to exclude all the pages that have "MT=1" in header 
how to exclude from varnish cache ?

i think it would be at /etc/varnish/default.vcl
under 
sub vcl_recv

but what is the syntax ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
  if ( beresp.http.MT == "1" ) {
    set beresp.ttl = 0s;
  }
}
```